# How to add spacing in between <div>

Tags: html, css

So I have a menu at the top of my page, but I can't figure out how to add spacing in between buttons. I just want a bit of space in between buttons so they don't look so sloppy.

Here's my menu. The code is below it.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <ul class="topbar">
    <a href="pages/index.html" class="fade">Home Page</a>
    <a href="pages/userprofile.html" class="fade">Profile</a>
    <a href="pages/createacc.html" class="fade">Create an Account</a>
    <a href="pages/settings.html" class="fade">User Settings</a>
    <a href="pages/contact.html" class="fade">Contact Us</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

/****************************/

.topbar {
    width: 700px ;
    Height:initial;
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, Only `li` are allowed in `ul`. Or Just remove the `ul` wrapper completely.

Comment: Tried any margins or padding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "buttons" should be placed inside list items `<li>`

```
<div>
  <ul class="topbar">
    <li><a href="pages/index.html" class="fade">Home Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="pages/userprofile.html" class="fade">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="pages/createacc.html" class="fade">Create an Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="pages/settings.html" class="fade">User Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="pages/contact.html" class="fade">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And about styling and spacing...

```
ul.topbar {
    width: 700px ;
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul.topbar li
{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 10px;
}

ul.topbar a
{
    font-family:Arial;
    color:#950095;
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul.topbar a:hover
{
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

And you can check it out **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/qXh3e/)**:

If for some sort of weird reason, you do not have access to the code generating the menu, you could use some jQuery to wrap `<li>` around your `<a>`:

```
$( "ul.topbar a" ).wrap( "<li></li>" );
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to compress your code into:

    "ul.topbar li
    {
        list-style-type:none;
        display:inline-block;
    }"

and I set the <a> tags to <li><a>

Answer (score 1):

The below should do it

```
.topbar a:not(:last-child){
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/32pSx/1/)

This selects all the `a` items in your menu, representing the menu choices, and adds a right margin to all except the last one.

That said, your HTML is invalid, you need to wrap your `a` within `li` elements, *or* change your HTML to:

```
<div class="topbar">
    <a href="pages/index.html" class="fade">Home Page</a>
    <a href="pages/userprofile.html" class="fade">Profile</a>
    <a href="pages/createacc.html" class="fade">Create an Account</a>
    <a href="pages/settings.html" class="fade">User Settings</a>
    <a href="pages/contact.html" class="fade">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ad to ur `<a>` tags display:inline-block and then treat them like divs.. put width height margins and paddings . [hope it works](http://jsfiddle.net/ic0o09988/T48kp/) ;)

```
.topbar a{
display:inline-block;
line-height:30px/*its standart but u can change it*/
padding:0 5px; /*this will putt space from left and right u can edit it too*/
/*keep in mid that the elemens with inline-block will fitt in the width of their parent element and make a new line if needed*/
}
```